# How do I display different control types per row in a WPF ListView

Tags: wpf, listview

I'm re-writting a .Net WinForm app in WPF.

I need to reproduce a ListView control that has 3 columns.

- The 1st column is just text.
- The 2nd column can be an image, a
  button, or empty.
- The 3rd column can contain TextBox, ComboBox,
  DateTimePicker, NumericUpDown, or a CheckBox!

This listview refreshes it's contents (including the types of controls) depending on what has been selected above.

[ListView screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kZ11w.jpg)

Unfortunately I'm new to WPF. I've been researching WPF ListView's and the binding process. But my gut reaction is that this is not a binding scenario (although I'm happy to be proved wrong).

So my questions are can the WPF ListView display different control types per row? If so, how?

Many thanks, Matt.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe will be useful to someone.

I think DataTemplateSelector can be used in this case. You should define your own selector
inherited from the class DataTemplateSelector and put there the logic what template to use based on the item. Then set it as ItemTemplateSelecto for ListView.

The detail information about DataTemplateSelector can be read from [here](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wpf-tutorial-how-to-use-a-datatemplateselector)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the `GridView` or a `DataGrid`. You'll need to manually specify your columns types instead of relying on auto-generated columns

Answer (score 0):

Here is a TextBlock and  CheckBox

```
    <ListView.View>
            <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="False" x:Name="gvWFbatches">
                <GridViewColumn Width="Auto">
                    <GridViewColumnHeader Content="Batch"/>
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock TextWrapping="NoWrap"  Text="{Binding Path=BatchName, Mode=OneWay}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Width="Auto">
                    <GridViewColumnHeader Content="QC"/>
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <CheckBox  IsChecked="{Binding Path=IncQC, Mode=OneWay}"  IsHitTestVisible="False" Focusable="False"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
```

Comment: You can have a different DataTemplate for each column to show the data as you wish.

Comment: With these column definitions, all rows in the first column will show a `TextBlock` and all rows in the second column will show a `CheckBox`. The OP's question states that in his or her `ListView`, different rows need to have different controls in one column, which is not solved by this answer.

Comment: "Depending on what has been selected above" is not clear and no comment nor question from OP in over 2 years.